# Show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0, 1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, signal-processing, wavelets

Show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0, 1]$.

Please help me. I have no idea.

Comment: Did you mean "converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1)$" instead? (Or are these equivalent in your context, e.g. $L^\infty$?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm correct, note that $h_k$ depends on n, then denote it as $h_{k,n}$. Note also that $$h_{k,n}(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{n},& t\in[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}),\\
0, &\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Therefore, $$\langle f,h_{k,n}\rangle=\int_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}} \sqrt{n}f(x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}f(\zeta_{k,n})$$ for some $\zeta_{k,n}\in (\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n})$, this latter given by the Mean Value Theorem for definite integrals. That shows $$f_n(x)=f(\zeta_{k,n})\ \text{if}\ x\in[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}).$$

Use uniform continuity of $f$ in $[0,1]$ to show uniform convergence.

PS. Excuse my bad english.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Can you please advise me explicitly that why $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly? I know that [0,1] is compact. Therefore, since f is continuous on the compact interval [0,1] then f is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Of course. By uniform continuity of $f$, you can show that given $\epsilon>0$ exists $N$ sufficiently large such that for all $n\geq N$ if $|x-y|<\frac{1}{n}$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. In particular, for all $n\geq N$ and $x\in [\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n})$, $|f(x)-f(\zeta_{k,n})|<\epsilon$. Therefore, $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Depending of the $L^p$-norm you can prove the rest.